# Pygame Cannot Blit An Image To A List Of Rectangles

Tags: python, pygame

I am working with pygame, and I thought it'd be a super neat idea to make it so that the bricks were automatically generated at the beginning of the game. So I made a function that asks for how many bricks you want generated, and then creates the "bodies" for those bricks in special locations and assigns them to a list. Then, in the while loop, I try to blit those with the according image. However, I get an error I have never seen before.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAPT1.png)

```
import pygame, sys
import random
import numpy
pygame.init()

def myPopulater(amountToMake, image, width, h):


    myBodies = []
    for i in range(amountToMake):
        r1 = numpy.random.randint(0, width)
        r2 = numpy.random.randint(0, h)
        myBodies = myBodies + image.get_rect()
        myBodies[i].x = r1
        myBodies[i].x = r2
    return myBodies

width = 500
h = 500

ball = pygame.image.load("c:\\python\\ball.png")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, h))

myList = myPopulater(25, ball, width, h)
while (1):
        #WHENEVER SOMETHING HAPPENS
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        screen.fill(black)
        for i in range(0, 25):
            screen.blit(ball, myList[i])
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: it's much better to include the error message ouput in the question, especially when it's a short message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you're trying to add the result of `image.get_rect()` to your `myBodies` list.

You should use the `list.append` method to add an element to a `list` object.

Change this line:

```
myBodies = myBodies + image.get_rect()
```

To this:

```
myBodies.append(image.get_rect())
```

That will fix your error.